# who command: What do the - + ? symbols represent with the -T option?

Tags: command-line, users, who

Through the `man who` appears the following for the `-T` option

```
  -T, -w, --mesg
          add user's message status as +, - or ?
```

According with some tutorials, if is executed `who -T` should appears these symbols.

In my case `-` appears for all the users logged through `tty` and `+` for all the users logged through `ssh` - nothing about `?`

What do the - + ? symbols represent with the -T option?

Answer (score 3):

The "message status" tells you whether the user accepts messages on that particular TTY.

Here, my shell session is running on `/dev/pts/3`:

```bsh
$ tty
/dev/pts/3
```

My message status on this TTY, as well as on the other TTYs that I'm using, is `+`, meaning I accept messages:

```bsh
$ who -T
kk       + pts/0        2022-04-23 14:32 (192.168.1.107)
kk       + pts/1        2022-04-23 13:02 (tmux(2971).%0)
kk       + pts/2        2022-04-23 13:02 (tmux(2971).%1)
kk       + pts/3        2022-04-23 13:02 (tmux(2971).%2)
kk       + pts/4        2022-04-23 14:32 (tmux(2971).%3)
```

I then turn off the ability for other users to send messages to me (using e.g. `write`; see `man write` and `man mesg`):

```bsh
$ mesg n
```

This affects the message status:

```bsh
$ who -T
kk       + pts/0        2022-04-23 14:32 (192.168.1.107)
kk       + pts/1        2022-04-23 13:02 (tmux(2971).%0)
kk       + pts/2        2022-04-23 13:02 (tmux(2971).%1)
kk       - pts/3        2022-04-23 13:02 (tmux(2971).%2)
kk       + pts/4        2022-04-23 14:32 (tmux(2971).%3)
```

If the message status is `?`, this means the terminal device is unknown.

The following is from the GNU `who` info manual (`info '(coreutils)who invocation'`), relating to the `-T` option:

> ```
> After each login name print a character indicating the user’s
> message status:
>
>      ‘+’ allowing ‘write’ messages
>      ‘-’ disallowing ‘write’ messages
>      ‘?’ cannot find terminal device
> ```

---

The `who` utility is a POSIX utility, and in the POSIX standard, the `-T` option adds a terminal state with four possible values: `+`, `-`, `?` and   (space).  [The specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/who.html) describes these like so:

> ```
>   +       The terminal allows write access to other users.
>
>   -       The terminal denies write access to other users.
>
>   ?       The terminal write-access state cannot be determined.
>
>   <space> This entry is not associated with a terminal.
> ```